# Apache daemon problem /etc/init.d/apache2

Tags: server, apache2, logrotate

For the last 5 weeks, I have monitored some strange behavior. Every week at logrotate process time, the init script `/etc/init.d/apache2` is being rotated as if it were a log file.

The first week it created another file `apache2.1` and emptied `apache2`.  The following week it made `apache2.2` and `apache2.1` and emptied `apache2`.  And so on.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6461 2015-04-26 06:25 apache2.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6461 2015-05-03 06:25 apache2.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6461 2015-05-10 06:25 apache2.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6461 2015-05-17 06:25 apache2.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 2015-05-24 06:25 apache2
```

I am not sure if it is an apache update bug or some scheduled job.
Here is my log rotation file:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        weekly
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 644 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
                fi
        endscript
}
```